Providing AD join variable for realm join to AD using Ansible not working
I am using an Ansible Playbook to join an Ubuntu VM to my AD domain using realm. I have a variable configured under vars in the playbook named ad_password. The password contains letters, numbers and special characters. I have tried both surrounding the password in double quotes and without any quotes at all. The task is as follows:
- name: Join the computer to the realm
  command: realm join -v {{ domain_controller }} --computer-ou "{{ ad_computer_ou }}" -U {{ ad_join_user }}%{{ ad_password }}
  register: realm_join

However, when I execute the playbook, it hangs forever on this task. I have tried multiple ways of trying to get the playbook to interactively supply the domain join password for the account specified in ad_join_user, but it either fails with an authentication error (not supplying the password correctly I assume) or with this example, hangs forever on this task.
When I hard code the password into the task, the domain join works just fine, such as below:
- name: Join the computer to the realm
  command: /bin/bash -c "echo MY_PASSWORD_PUT_HERE | realm join -v {{ domain_controller }} --computer-ou "{{ ad_computer_ou }}" -U {{ ad_join_user }}"
  register: realm_join

I have tried the command module, as well as the shell module and nothing is working to specify the password from a variable (or from an encrypted variable within an Ansible vault file).

Look at larsks second example, which uses args with stdin. Might work.

Or use ansible.buitlin.expect. Answer on Reddit
